# Measuring drawn line length with turf.js and mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying to build out the functionality to measure a line that a user draws over a Mapbox map, using turf.js 'length' feature.

That said, I'm a coding newb - I know just barely enough to be dangerous.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to draw both areas and lines, and have their respective measures returned (area for polygons, lengths for line strings).

Can anyone offer insight as to why this code doesn't work?

https://jsfiddle.net/knxwu342

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Line Test</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }

    .calculation-box-length {
        height: 75px;
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        left: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

</style>

<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js'> 
</script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.9/mapbox-gl-draw.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.9/mapbox-gl-draw.css' type='text/css'/>

<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'> 
</script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>

<div class='calculation-box-length'>
<p>Length:</p>
<div id='calculated-length'></div>
</div>

<nav id="menu"></nav>

<script>mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWJsYWNrbGluIiwiYSI6ImNqaWMxcGk2MzAwd3YzbG1oeW4yOHppdnYifQ.xdb-2slu5LapzpuMCiKzQQ';

//*********-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**********
//Create new map object
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container id
style: 'mapbox://styles/mblacklin/cjii8o7w91g9o2stcktaeixai', // stylesheet location
center: [-117.572737, 51.746916], // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 16 // starting zoom
});
//*********-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**********
// Add navigation controls to the map
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());


//*********-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**********
// Add the ability to draw geometries and display their measurements
//
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
displayControlsDefault: false,
controls: {
    line_string: true,
    polygon: true,
    trash: true
}
});

map.addControl(draw);

map.on('draw.create.', updateLength);
map.on('draw.delete', updateLength);
map.on('draw.update', updateLength);

function updateLength(e) {
var data = draw.getAll();
var answer = document.getElementById('calculated-length');
if (data.features.length > 0) {
    var length = turf.length(data);
    // restrict to area to 2 decimal points
    answer.innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + length + '</strong></p><p> meters</p>';
} else {
    answer.innerHTML = '';
    if (e.type !== 'draw.delete') alert("Use the draw tools in the upper right to calculate a distance");
}
};
//
//*********-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**********  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two little problems in your code:

1. There is a typo in your '*draw.create*' listener. Just remove the point after *create*:

   map.on('draw.create', updateLength);
2. The version of Turf you are using is too old and does not seem to have the length function. Try using the most recent one: https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js